# Prove that the equation $ e^{x}+x^{3}=10+x $ has a unique solution on the open interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that the equation
$$
e^{x}+x^{3}=10+x
$$
has a unique solution on the open interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Letting $f(x)=e^{x}+x^{3}-10-x$, $f(0)<0$ and $f(10)>0$, so by the IVT there must be a solution in the interval $(0,10)$.

Now I must show there cannot be more than one solution.  Generally for these proofs you assume that there is at least 2 solutions and show a contradiction.  Letting the solutions be a and b ($a<b$ WLOG) I want to use Rolle's theorem to show that $f'(x)=e^{x}+3x^{2}-1$ cannot be zero (giving the contradiction).  The problem is $f'(0)=0$.  So how do I proceed?

Comment: For a first step you can find upper and lower bounds for the set of solutions by noticing that $e^x > x^3 - x - 10$ for $x > b$ and $x^3 < 10 + x - e^x$ for $x<a$ by asymptotics of $e^x$ and $x^3$ for $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: I would go for finding the zeroes of $f'$ and calculating (or at least bounding) $f$ in those points.

Comment: A quick look at the function suggests that _all_ roots necessarily are within $(-1,10)$. Seeing that there are only two extrema and both with negative function value will give you the uniqueness.

Comment: Just a small comment: This is not an "algebraic equation" since it involves the transcendental function $e^x$.  It is a transcendental equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can observe that if $x <-1$ then $X^3-X < 0$, thus
$$f(x) <e^{-1}-10 <-9$$

Also if $x \in [-1, 1]$ we have $x^3 \leq 1$ and $-x \leq 1$ thus 
$$f(x) \leq e+2-10 < -5$$

Therefore there is no solution $x \leq 1$.

Now apply your technique on $(1, \infty)$. It is easy to show tha on this interval $f'(x) >0$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ups, ty. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Prove that $f(x)$ is injective over positive real numbers.

$$f'(x) > 0, \forall x\geq0 \text{ appart for 0  and } f\in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \implies f \text{ injective } $$

Then $\forall(a, b) \in \mathbb{R^+}^2, f(a) = f(b) \iff a=b$

And $\forall x<0, f(x) < 0$ as $x^3-x\leq1$ and $e^x<1$

Comment: $f' > 0$ away from $0$ is false.

Comment: How is it false? It's actually true.

Comment: Use IVT on $-.2$ and $-.3$ for example.

Comment: [W|A link for reference](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28x%29%2B3x*x-1+%3D+0)

Comment: Indeed, I edited.

Comment: Still incorrect... I suggest you rework the answer and undelete after the overhaul is complete (as Henning Makholm did too)

Comment: Could you point out what is incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20172/discussion-between-alexr-and-servabat).

Comment: Indeed, I've been forgetting it in my edits. By the way, sorry I'm not comfortable with that chat thing, tried but couldn't answer. Also I'd be glad if you could explain how to delete / undelete an answer.

Comment: The whole point is that $f$ isn't even injective in the first place for obvious reasons. The answer cannot be salvaged by edits, it needs a complete rework of strategy. Sorry for the harsh wording.

Comment: There should be a "delete" link next to the "edit" link below your post.

Comment: Well it is injective over $\mathbb{R^+}$ as then $f'>0$. And for negatives, f is strictly negative, so has no roots.

Comment: Okay with that, but can you rigorously prove that without W|A?

Comment: I've never been using W|A (that's why I've wrongly been assuming f'(x) to be strictly positive in a first place). $f''(x) > 0, \forall x>0, f'(0)=0$ should be sufficient.